# SSRS Page Breaks. Past the end of my rope

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

(This is for SSRS 2012)

Hey guys.  I know this really isn't the way to do things, but I am just completely done struggling with this.

Here is a zipped-up .rdl file for a report I'm working on: http://www.flowdex.net/files/amalgam_rdl.zip.  Included in the .zip file is a .pdf with a typical output of that report.

I am getting several phantom page breaks that I simply cannot understand.  I have scoured the internet, including stack overflow, and none of the regular suggestions have worked.  I have made *sure* everything fits within the dimensions of a page, margins included, and have looked at the properties of every element in the report.  Nothing gives ANY CLUE WHATSOEVER why a blank page must be inserted within a tablix that goes past one page, or why there is a page break in-between the two tablixes.

I don't know how viewing my .rdl will work... obviously you're not getting a database, so you won't have any way to test it.  All I'm asking is for someone to take a quick glance at how everything is formatted and let me know if anything major stands out.

Sorry for the terseness, and I guess I'd understand if this question gets ignored / rejected.  I just do not understand why this is so difficult.  Teaching myself PHP was a million times easier than finding a stupid page break in SSRS.

Thanks in advance, and apologies again for being rude.  This is crazy frustrating.

Comment: Best to post screen shots. Not going to download random zip files.

Comment: It looks to me like what you should do is take the DIV6 image and [Seiten] move them over to the left a little, then take the report body and collapse it to be right up against them.  Right now, with your margins I think you are going over and it creates that phantom page thing.

Comment: Snowlockkk - I'm not sure how images will help you, but I totally understand where you're coming from.  I wasn't sure how to deliver this myself.  I put together an imgur album of the resultant .pdf: https://imgur.com/gallery/3RI4b.  You can see Jesse's screenshot below for context on how the .rdl itself looks.

Comment: Jesse - thanks for the suggestion.  I've shifted that logo (and the report body) a couple hundred thousand times, but truthfully I didn't go the distance insofar as to really test how skinny I could possibly make the report.  I've mostly been riding the edge, as it were, yet still assuming I was within bounds.  I'm busy today but I can do some more testing tonight and tomorrow morning, and I'll try that first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like what you should do is take the DIV6 image and [Seiten] move them over to the left a little, then take the report body and collapse it to be right up against them.  Right now, with your margins I think you are going over and it creates that phantom page thing.

[image: Screenshot Below]

Answer (score 0):

Put visible borders onto *everything*.  Start with the obvious: tablix's,text boxes, lists, images but also add to Report, Header, Footer, Body etc.

Make them all a different **colour**.  You should then see which object is spilling onto the other page.

Note:  adding a border adds a pixel (or point) to the width and height, so make sure you adjust for that when removing them or identifying the culprit.

**Plan B:**
From the screenshot, your empty page does not have a Batch:[Name] which indicates it could the way you are calculating your group maybe causing the problem  (if it was due to pushing an element too wide, the header should have the same [Name] as the previous page.